# Read Oracle stored procedure and represent it as XML

Tags: php, oracle, stored-procedures, simplexml

I want to do following: Make Oracle stored procedure for read all data from database I was trying with SELECT * FROM base; But this is not working with Oracle.
But maybe I need to do it little more different because I want to do something like this:
I want to have Procedure that will return me XML representation of data:
Here is code that I am using for making XML document, AND my questions is how to change it so I can use this code to send data from stored procedure.

Code:

```
require_once('test_xml.php');
$library = array(
    'book' => array(
        array(
            'authorFirst' => 'Mark',
            'authorLast' => 'Twain',
            'title' => 'The Innocents Abroad'
        ),
        array(
            'authorFirst' => 'Charles',
            'authorLast' => 'Dickens',
            'title' => 'Oliver Twist'
        )
    )
);
$ArrayToXml=new ArrayToXml();
echo $ArrayToXml->toXml($library);
```

And class for making XML:

```
class ArrayToXML
{
    /**
     * The main function for converting to an XML document.
     * Pass in a multi dimensional array and this recrusively loops through and builds up an XML document.
     *
     * @param array $data
     * @param string $rootNodeName - what you want the root node to be - defaultsto data.
     * @param SimpleXMLElement $xml - should only be used recursively
     * @return string XML
     */
    public static function toXml($data, $rootNodeName = 'data', &$xml=null)
    {
        // turn off compatibility mode as simple xml throws a wobbly if you don't.
        if (ini_get('zend.ze1_compatibility_mode') == 1)
        {
            ini_set ('zend.ze1_compatibility_mode', 0);
        }

        if (is_null($xml))
        {
            $xml = simplexml_load_string("<".key($data)."s/>");
        }

        // loop through the data passed in.
        foreach($data as $key => $value)
        {
            // if numeric key, assume array of rootNodeName elements
            if (is_numeric($key))
            {
                $key = $rootNodeName;
            }

            // delete any char not allowed in XML element names
            $key = preg_replace('/[^a-z0-9\-\_\.\:]/i', '', $key);

            // if there is another array found recrusively call this function
            if (is_array($value))
            {
                // create a new node unless this is an array of elements
                $node = ArrayToXML::isAssoc($value) ? $xml->addChild($key) : $xml;

                // recrusive call - pass $key as the new rootNodeName
                ArrayToXML::toXml($value, $key, $node);
            }
            else
            {
                // add single node.
                $value = htmlentities($value);
                $xml->addChild($key,$value);
            }

        }
        // pass back as string. or simple xml object if you want!
        return $xml->asXML();
    }

    // determine if a variable is an associative array
    public static function isAssoc( $array ) {
        return (is_array($array) && 0 !== count(array_diff_key($array, array_keys(array_keys($array)))));
    }
}
```

Please help I have no idea how to implement this into SELECT * statement of stored procedure.

Thank you

Comment: You may want to look into DBMS_XMLGEN, which can convert any query into XML.  For example: `select dbms_xmlgen.getxml('select * from dual') from dual;`.

Comment: Hi thank's for reply. I want to just send back XML as result. Everything else stays normal. So normal reading from database and then represent for example data array into XML, and I have class for representing that. Just don't know how from stored procedure send back array of data that I can convert.

Comment: I guess I didn't directly answer your question; my suggestion was to use SQL to convert the data into XML, which could then be passed as a CLOB.  I don't want to start a whole "where do I store the business logic?" discussion, but if you're going to use a stored procedure anyway you might as well put most of your logic in it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can read all data from the entire database. You must create separate "select" statements for each table.